# Not able to run Cosmos DB Change Feed Trigger Azure Function locally

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-changefeed

I am not able to run Cosmos DB Change Feed Trigger function locally.

Cosmos DB Change Feed Trigger Azure Function:

```
public static class NotificationChangeFeed
    {
        [FunctionName("NotificationChangeFeed")]
        public static async Task Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "FleetHubNotifications",
            collectionName: "Notification",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection",
            CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true,
            LeaseCollectionName = "leases")]IReadOnlyList<Document> input,
            [Inject] ILoggingService loggingService,
            [Inject] IEmailProcessor emailProcessor)
        {
            var logger = new Logger(loggingService);

            try
            {
                if (input != null && input.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (Document document in input)
                    {
                        string requestBody = document.ToString();
                        var notification = requestBody.AsPoco<Notification>();

                        var result = await emailProcessor.HandleEmailAsync(notification, logger);

                        if (result)
                        {
                            logger.Info($"Email Notification sent successfully for file name: {document.Id}");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            logger.Warning($"Unable to process document for Email Notification for file with name: {document.Id}");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error($"Unable to process Documents for Email Notification for Files: {input?.Count}", ex,
                    nameof(NotificationChangeFeed));
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": "false",
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard ": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "CosmosDbId": "FleetHubNotifications",
    //Localhost
    "CosmoDbAuthKey": "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==",
    "CosmoDbEndpoint": "https://localhost:8081/",
    "CosmosDBConnection": "AccountEndpoint=https://localhost:8081/;AccountKey=C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==",
}
}
```

When I press F5, it got stuck in the console window.(As shown in the below screen shot)

Also not able call http trigger functions. Getting below error while calling:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7071

Any thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah in that part you only get the endpoints of the http functions. The other functions are also initialized and waiting for an event of whatever type. Yo can see it here: Found the following functions, 4 http trigger the other 2 are blob trigger.

[image]

If you want to debug your NotificationChangeFeed function you will have to create a new document on the DB and have the function runing and waiting for that event. And you will see the telemetry in the console and you can debug the function.

Comment: But i am not able call event http trigger functions. Getting "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7071"

Comment: But you are trying to run the NotificationChangeFeed?? Or the other http functions??

Comment: I am trying to run both http trigger and cosmos db trigger same time.

Comment: I dont knwo then, we need more info. If you have the functions running and make a call from the postman to this endpoint http://localhost:7071/api/AddOrUpdateEmailTemplate, you are getting and ECONNREFUSED??

Comment: yes correct! while calling this via postman i am getting the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you have the function runing?? Cause I try it whit my function stopped and I get the same message. If dont I don``t really know man why you are getting that error.